# How to Copy all the site collections from one web application to another?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development

I have an two web-applications. https://source.company.com and https://destination.company.com.
I want to make a copy of the site collection from source to destination within the same farm.

On source, I have two site collections - sourcecollection1 and sourcecollection2. These have a lot of documents, libraries and document collections. Many of the artifacts are attached to item IDs and several documents have versioning associated to them. I need them intact and match on the destination as well.
ShareGate doesn't allow this even with *INSANE MODE* as it is *On-Premise*.
Can anyone help me with this? A Powershell Script of a C# console application would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `Backup-SPSite` and `Restore-SPSite`. This will bring the site over with full fidelity while changing the Site.ID value (must be unique per farm).